# Question about de Broglie Waves?

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, quantum-gravity

Is photon interaction , electrostatic interaction outside the nucleus and gravitational interaction is all due to electromagnetic waves ? and CAN be identified as with the de Broglie waves ?

I thought of a theory in which is assuming that photon interaction , electrostatic interaction outside the nucleus and gravitational interaction is all due to electromagnetic waves and can be identified as with the de Broglie waves in order to explain how the force of gravitation act between particles . So can this assumption stand a chance of being theoretically and experimentally correct .
Please add your comments regarding this in your answer and please explain why or why not .

Answer (score 1):

At everyday energies electrostatic interactions (including photons) are described to extremely high accuracy by quantum field theory, and specifically [quantum electrodynamics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_electrodynamics).

QED is more complex than simply treating everything as an electromagnetic wave or indeed a de Broglie wave. It predicts observations to essentially perfect accuracy and does not involve gravitation in any way. There is no way to describe gravitation as a side effect of electrostatic interactions.